# Unity 3D and Mixamo Animation -- Feet Inside of ground

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have a weird problem I can't figure out. I'm new enough to Unity 3D I have a hard time even posing the questions sometimes.

Take a careful look at this picture where I drew the red circles:
[image]

The problem is that both in the actual game *and in the animation preview*, this Mixamo character, using the Mixamo running animation, shows her feet under the ground. Actually, this is a problem with all animations. She does NOT start out under the ground (and in fact starts above ground.) But when the game runs, she falls to the ground (well, she doesn't really fall since she has no ridge body. She appears suddenly at level 0, which you'd think is right on the ground, but in fact it shows her a foot or two under the ground), and the animation then plays with her too low. She doesn't have a ridged body, so that is not the problem.

You can also see my settings for the animation. I've played around with all of them and can't fix it. This happens whether or not I apply root motion or foot IK.

Is there a way to 'lift' the animation up so that it is right on the ground?

Comment: Update: looks like I *can* fix it by putting her slight above ground with certain settings (still experimenting which ones allow it). Not the fix I was hoping for. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: Did you check the collider on the floor? And the collider on the character? You are making a game, and not looking for a fix. If nothing seems wrong, you could try re-exporting the Mixamo animations and reimporting them.

Comment: Collider on ground is fine. Collider on character -- for some reason -- doesn't work correctly on it's own if I add a ridge body. Falls right through floor. But if I add a capsule collider instead of a mesh, and then carefully adjust, I can make it look right so she 'falls' to be right on the floor.

Comment: I hadn't thought to reimport, I'll try that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reimporting fixed the problem. I do not know why. It seems that when you play with the animations, they sometimes get corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

I just found an issue in Unity. When i kept the T-Pose Model (Skinned) in a folder and the animation of it in another folder then the Animations turn out to misbehave. Like Legs twitching or parts of body going down.  When I brought the T-Pose and other animations together in one folder and updated the reference in Rig of T-Pose then all became normal.

Answer (score 1):

One shitty basic problem is just:

[image]

There's an obscure setting actually on "Layers" in Animator, on the "base" layer you have to explicitly turn on "IK Pass".

Only in very unusual situations would you want this "off", just another bizarre mistake by Unity.